Way to unignore files and directories in Surround SCM?
This is a variant to this SO question.
Is there a way to unignore files and directories via an .sscmignore file?
This should override the server setting as well as any transitive ignore rules inherited from namesake files in parent directories.
SSCM seems to largely mimic what git does (or perhaps it's the other way around?) and in .gitignore we would simply prefix the file or directory using ! to unignore it.
I tried this in SSCM, but either SSCM deviates from git here or it simply does not support unignoring files and directories.
